# Passing arrays with different content swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am struggling and I hope that someone can help me. I have one view controller that contains six buttons. Depending on which button the user clicks different content should be shown in the table view. I have created arrays and the structure is always the same. My firstViecontroller that is connected to the viewcontroller in the storyboard is named: IntroViewController. The second one is named " Cat1TableViewcontroller.

I thought that I have done alle necessary steps. The program runs, but when i click on one of the buttons the table is empty.

Here is what I did for my "first" ViewControllerFile:

```
class IntroViewController: UIViewController
{
 var contentMode = 0

@IBAction func draussen(_ sender: Any)
{
    contentMode = 1
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTable", sender: self)
}


@IBAction func kiez(_ sender: Any)
{
    contentMode = 2
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTable", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func fahren(_ sender: Any)
{
    contentMode = 3
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTable", sender: self)
}


@IBAction func photo(_ sender: Any)
{
    contentMode = 4
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTable", sender: self)
}


@IBAction func essen(_ sender: Any)
{
    contentMode = 5
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTable", sender: self)

}

@IBAction func schwitzen(_ sender: Any)
{
    contentMode = 6
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTable", sender: self)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

My "second" viewcontroller copies the arrays(in the action function) to an empty array and works with it further (in order to pass data to the next view controller)

Here is the part of the class that should show only the arraycontent that has been selected by the user via clicking the button.

```
class Cat1TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
var spots:[Spot] = []
var spot2:[Spot] = [

    Spot(name:"Rye Playland", type:"Vergnügungspark am Strand",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhhjh",location:"Rye",phone:"78787878787",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Splish Splash", type:"Wasserpark",description:"hjhjhjhjhjjhjhjjh",location:"Long Island",phone:"7878787878777878",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Kotti Berliner Döner", type:"Türkisches Essen",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjjhjhjhjhjhjhjj",location:"Brooklyn",phone:"78787878787878787878",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Die größte Pizzascheibe der Welt", type:"Italienisches Essen",description:"jhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhj",location:"Yonkers",phone:"78787878787878",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Die billigste Pizzascheibe der Welt", type:"Italienisches Essen",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjjh", location:"Manhattan",phone:"8989898989",image:"skyline", isVisited: false)

    ]

 var spot3:[Spot] = [
    Spot(name:"Sate in Queens", type:"Asiatisches Essen",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjh",location:"Queens",phone:"787878787787", image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Intrepid", type:"Museum",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjh",location:"Manhattan",phone:"787878787878787",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Fire Island", type:"Strand",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhj",location:"Long Island",phone:"78788787878787",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Jones Beach", type:"Strand",description:"hjhjhjhjjhjh",location:"Long Island",phone:"78787878787878787878", image:"skyline", isVisited: false)

    ]
var spot4:[Spot] = [

Spot(name:"Waterfront in Yonkers", type:"Aussicht",description:"jhjhjhjhjhjhjjh",location:"Yonkers",phone:"8989898989899", image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
Spot(name:"Dim Sum in Queens", type:"Asiatisches Essen",description:"hjhjhjjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjh",location:"Queens",phone:"7878787878787", image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
Spot(name:"Koreanisches Spa", type:"Wellness",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhj",location:"Queens",phone:"787878787878878",image:"skyline", isVisited: false)
]


 var spot5:[Spot] = [
Spot(name:"Queens Botanischer Garten", type:"Botanischer Garten",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhj", location:"Queens",phone:"78787878787878",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
Spot(name:"Open Air Kino", type:"Kino",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhj",location:"Brooklyn",phone:"89989898989898", image:"skyline", isVisited: false)
]


var spot6:[Spot] = [
    Spot(name:"Orchard Beach", type:"Strand",description:"jkjkjkjkjkkjkkjkjkjkjkjkjkjkjkjkjkj",location:"Bronx",phone:"7878787878", image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Paddeln am Hudson River", type:"Natur und Bewegung",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhj",location:"Hudson",phone:"7787878787878787",image:"skyline", isVisited: false),
    Spot(name:"Umsonst und Draussen", type:"Washington Park",description:"hjhjhjhjhjhjhjhjhhhhhhhhghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghghgjhjh",location:"Manhattan",phone:"8989898989898", image:"skyline", isVisited: false)

]




override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    // we tell the table view that there is only one section and return the total number of spots as stored in the array

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 1
    {
        spots = spot1
    }

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 2
    {
        spots = spot2
    }

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 3
    {
        spots = spot3
    }

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 4
    {
        spots = spot4
    }
    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 5
    {
        spots = spot5
    }
    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 6
    {
        spots = spot6
    }

    return spots.count

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
indexPath: IndexPath)->UITableViewCell
{
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SpotTableViewCell// because I am 
using a custom cell I am converting to the specific cell type
    // configure the cell

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 1
    {
        spots = spot1

    }

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 2
    {
        spots = spot2
    }

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 3
    {
        spots = spot3
    }

    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 4
    {
        spots = spot4
    }
    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 5
    {
        spots = spot5
    }
    if IntroViewController().contentMode == 6
    {
        spots = spot6

    }

    cell.nameLabel.text = spots[indexPath.row].name
    cell.locationLabel.text = spots[indexPath.row].location
    cell.typeLabel.text = spots[indexPath.row].type
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = 
  UIImage(named:spots[indexPath.row].image)

    //cell.heartImageView.isHidden = spots[indexPath.row]isVisited ? 
 false : true
    return cell
}
```

I am happy for any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store your data which should get accessed from different UIViewControllers in a separate Service like here:

```
class DataFactory {

    var contentMode = 0

    static let sharedInstance : DataFactory = {
        let instance = DataFactory()
        return instance
    }()

    var spot2:[Spot] = []
    ...
```

Than you access this service in your ViewControllers like this:

```
 //Setting the content mode
 DataFactory.sharedInstance.contentMode = 1

 //Getting the result array 
 let yourArray = DataFactory.sharedInstance.spot2
```

You could also store your data in a array in array and could use your contentMode indicator as index.

Example:

```
//two dimensional array of spots
var spots = [[Spot]]();

//than you can store your spot arrays inside this two dimensional array
spots.append(spot2);

//accessing the spots via contentMode-Index (I would rename the contentMode to spotsIndex or something similar)
let currentSpots = spots[self.contentMode];
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you help me with your 2nd suggestion? I am getting crazy, because I think that I am so close.

Comment: No problem. You can check the question as solved, if everything is clear now